# How to Create a path in my shell for windows?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a question, I created a script but I need to create a path, to find my cassandra folder to execute `cqlsh`, this is the route

```
C:/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/bin/cqlsh
```

the problem is because I am in windows not in linux, and I want to see if possible to create an a path in case that I need to pass my script to my team. but you know your cassandra db is in another route for that reason I want to do that because I need to execute this script

example

```
route= /../cassandra3.11.4/bin/cqlsh

 $route -k fsainstqual -e "TRUNCATE instrumentmanufacturer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you don't know how to mix Windows drive letters and Linux directory handling (which does not have drives), you'll need mounting points, as you can see in following `mount` excerpt on my PC, where I have a Linux app installed:

```
Prompt>mount
...
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
E: on /mnt/e type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

In top of that, on my root directory, I've created symlinks to those mounted directories:

```
Prompt>cd /
Prompt>$ ls -ltra | grep "\->"
lrwxrwxrwx  2 root  root  6 Nov 23  2017 C -> /mnt/c
lrwxrwxrwx  2 root  root  6 Nov 14 12:00 E -> /mnt/e
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to clarify your question buddy.

If you want to change your current directory, you can use "cd" command as in linux shell.

If you want to create a path use "md" or "mkdir" command.

Here is the help in windows OS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/md